# Does NOT outputing HTML for a navigation menu in mobile hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, navigation, hidden-text, menu

I have a menu visible in Desktop and Tablet, which shows all the categories available (in a Category Page).

That menu is hidden by a button in Mobile, and I use Javascript to NOT output the menu HTML until it is needed (to save HTML nodes and thus get better performance).

The question is, will it hurt SEO? This is marked as "less words"in some tools due to them scanning only the output DOM

The triggering button is this:

`<button class="Sidebar_categoriesToggler__eE1o7" aria-label="Open categories menu">Categories</button>`